# boost::thread: Segfault when running optimized version

Tags: multithreading, segmentation-fault, boost-thread

I have trouble getting `boost:thread` to work. It runs fine when compiling without optimization:

```
g++ -o test-thread test-thread.cpp -lboost_thread-gcc-mt-s -lpthread
./test-thread
```

But a version that's compiled with optimizations crashes

```
g++ -O2 -o test-thread test-thread.cpp -lboost_thread-gcc-mt-s -lpthread
./test-thread
Segmentation fault
```

Does anyone know what might be the reason?

Here is the code I am using:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

void task1() {
  // do something
}
void task2() {
  // do something
}

int main (int argc, char ** argv) {
  using namespace boost;

  function0<void> f1(&task1);
  function0<void> f2(&task2);

  thread thread_1(f1);
  thread thread_2(f2);

  // do other stuff 
  thread_2.join();
  thread_1.join();
  return 0;
}
```

P.S.: I am using boost 1.32 on ubuntu linux.

**UPDATE:**

Here is where it crashes in the debugger (where line 37 is the one with `thread_2.join();` in my original code):

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x080499e0 in boost::thread::join ()
#1  0x080496b8 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbfea3eb4) at ../src/test-thread.cpp:37
```

Here are my actual two functions:

```
void task1() {
  std::cerr << "THREAD 1 START" << std::endl;
  for(double i=0; i<999999; ++i){
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
  }
  std::cerr << "THREAD 1 END" << std::endl;
}

void task2() {
  std::cerr << "THREAD 2 START" << std::endl;
  for(double i=0; i<999999; ++i){
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
  }
  std::cerr << "THREAD 2 END" << std::endl;
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Not that it matters, but using a double for the index in your for loop is definitely odd...

Comment: Haha, that's right! I had used the loop index before to compute sin() values etc.

Comment: One more question: does the segfault occur right away, or does thread 2 finish printing its output?

Comment: I found the solution, see my own answer below. Thanks for all the help again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the bug! I had linked against the wrong version of the library. I had been using `boost_thread-gcc-mt-s`, but it works with `boost_thread-gcc-mt` instead:

```
g++ -O2 -o test-thread test-thread.cpp -lboost_thread-gcc-mt -lpthread
```

I looked into the boost documentation, but I couldn't find any information about what the differences between those library versions are. There is also a `boost_thread-gcc-mt-d`, which I assume is the debug version, but linking against that one always results in binaries that segfault, even when compiling with `-g`. But at least I can run the threads now.

Answer (score 3):

Could you make sure that core dumps are active (`ulimit -c unlimited`), compile with symbols (-O2 -g), run, and open the stack trace in gdb? (`gdb test-thread core`, then type `backtrace` at the `gdb` prompt, `quit` to quit)

> **UPDATE**
>
> Based on the backtrace, the
>   segmentation fault occurs in
>   `boost::thread::join`.  Could you
>   re-open the core and:
>
> - obtain a disassembly of the `boost::thread::join` method:
>
>   - `disassemble boost::thread::join`
>   - `disassemble`
> - obtain a dump of the registers:
>
>   - `info registers`
>
> The implementation of
>   `boost::thread::join` (boost 1.32
>   official source) is pretty
>   straight-forward, so unless the Ubuntu
>   binaries grossly diverge from the
>   official code (which we'll hopefully find out from the disassembly), there are only two
>   possible causes for the segmentation
>   fault.
>
> **Can you also confirm how far in their printouts the two threads got before the segmentation fault?**
>
> ```
> void thread::join()
> {
>     int res = 0;
> #if defined(BOOST_HAS_WINTHREADS)
>     res = WaitForSingleObject(reinterpret_cast<HANDLE>(m_thread), INFINITE);
>     assert(res == WAIT_OBJECT_0);
>     res = CloseHandle(reinterpret_cast<HANDLE>(m_thread));
>     assert(res);
> #elif defined(BOOST_HAS_PTHREADS)
>     res = pthread_join(m_thread, 0);
>     assert(res == 0);
> #elif defined(BOOST_HAS_MPTASKS)
>     OSStatus lStatus = threads::mac::detail::safe_wait_on_queue(
>         m_pJoinQueueID, NULL, NULL, NULL, kDurationForever);
>     assert(lStatus == noErr);
> #endif
>     // This isn't a race condition since any race that could occur would
>     // have us in undefined behavior territory any way.
>     m_joinable = false;
> }
> ```

Usual causes for these kinds of problems:

- uninitialized variables
- variables that are accessed by both threads that were not marked `volatile`
- inlined calls and/or unrolled loops (whose stack frame size is the sum of all inlined method instances' stack frames) being called recursively and overflowing the stack much faster than the non-inlined versions

Comment: Thanks so much for your help again. I found the solution now. I posted it as a separate answer.